# backbone.js click event not registering

Tags: click, backbone.js

I've been having trouble getting click events working through my item_match_result function.

I've tried putting the item_match_result in the ItemList view, seeing as that is the parent, but couldn't get that working either, and it really does belong in the ItemMatch view.

Any suggestions??

```
MyApp.Views.ItemList = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'li',
    className:'item_list',
    ...

    render_item_match: function(model){
            var item_match = new MyApp.Views.ItemMatch({model:model});
        $(this.el).append(item_match.el);
        }


});

MyApp.Views.ItemMatch = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'a',
    className: 'item_match_result',

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this,"item_match_result");
        this.render();
    },


    events : {
        "click a.item_result": "item_match_result"
    },

    render : function(){
        this.el = HandlebarsTemplates['items/itemSearchResultItem'](this.model.attributes);

    },

    item_match_result: function(){
     console.log(this);
    }
});


})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't replace this.el and have it still work. You just killed the element that the event is bound to. If you do that you'll need to run `this.delegateEvents()` again to rebind it.

```
MyApp.Views.ItemMatch = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'a',
    className: 'item_match_result',

    initialize: function(){
        _.bindAll(this,"item_match_result");
        this.render();
    },


    events : {
        "click a.item_result": "item_match_result"
    },

    render : function(){
        this.el = HandlebarsTemplates['items/itemSearchResultItem'](this.model.attributes);

        this.delegateEvents()

    },

    item_match_result: function(){
     console.log(this);
    }
});
```

Comment: the `delegateEvents` didn't actually work for me Harry, but I used `$(this.el).html(Handlebars...)` and that got it working so I gave you the points for pointing me in the right direction.